# Django Soft deletion and generic relationship manager

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 2.0 in a project and I'm implementing a soft delete function so I can recover deleted objects.

I've used this  [this implementation](https://medium.com/@adriennedomingus/soft-deletion-in-django-e4882581c340) of soft deletion in my Django project, and it works fine. But some models have GenericRelation with objects that may be soft deleted. Is there a way to implement a GenericRelationManager like the BaseModelManager, that will ignore soft deleted objects?

For example, suppose I have the following code (borrowed from [this site](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/13/how-to-use-generic-relations.html)):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Activity(BaseModel):
    FAVORITE = 'F'
    LIKE = 'L'
    UP_VOTE = 'U'
    DOWN_VOTE = 'D'
    ACTIVITY_TYPES = (
        (FAVORITE, 'Favorite'),
        (LIKE, 'Like'),
        (UP_VOTE, 'Up Vote'),
        (DOWN_VOTE, 'Down Vote'),
    )


    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    activity_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACTIVITY_TYPES)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # Below the mandatory fields for generic relation
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

And

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

from activities.models import Activity


class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    likes = GenericRelation(Activity)

class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    activities = GenericRelation(Activity)

class Answer(models.Model):
    ...
    votes = GenericRelation(Activity)

class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    likes = GenericRelation(Activity)
```

If I soft delete an activity, I would still be able to find the soft deleted activity through these GenericRelations. Can I make an implementation of GenericRelation that will behave just like the BaseModelManager, ignoring soft deleted activities?